# Bootstrap modal shows even if the input is empty

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've a modal attached to a button. When the inputs are empty, it is not supposed to show. How can I do that?

```
<form data-toggle="modal">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="name" required>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tranfer-modal" type="submit">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</form>

<section class="edit-dealermodal-wrapper" >
    <div class="modal-wrapper light-modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal fade" id="tranfer-modal" role="dialog"
             aria-labelledby="tranfer-modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                        <div class="sweet-alert">
                            <img src="{{asset('assets/admin')}}/images/icon-warning.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                            <h2 class="mt-3">Are you sure want to delete this branch?</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="justify-content: center;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn form-button" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn form-button btn-success update-branch">Yes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can manully show hide modals using `$('#yourModalId').modal('show');`  and `$('#yourModalId').modal('hide');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, the model will be shown irrespective of whether there is value in the text box or not. To prevent that you add an `onClick` event to the button and the function it calls determines whether to open the model or not.

```
 <button data-toggle="modal" onClick="openModel()" type="button">
```

And javascript function is -

```
function openModel(){
  if(document.getElementById('input1').value != ''){
    $('#tranfer-modal').modal('show')
  }
}
```

You can also add a click event using the jquery logic( Also id, data-* attributes are not required).

```
<button  type="button">
```

In js

```
 $('button').on('click',function(){
        if($('#input1').val() !=''){
     $('#tranfer-modal').modal('show');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the button disable, until text box is filled with required value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').attr('disabled',true);

    $('#txtBox').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0){
            $('.btn').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    })
});
```